# How do i prove this is the second derivative

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a real function defined on $[a,b]$.

Assume $f$ is twice differentiable.

How do i prove that $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-2f(a)+f(a-h)}{h^2}=f''(a)$?

I know that it can be divided into $f(a+h)-f(a)-(f(a)-f(a-h))$, but next i don't have any idea..

Comment: Did you try L'hopital's Rule?

Comment: Or alternatively you can Taylor expand the numerator. It is easier than it looks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps:
$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
Then you use $g(x)=f'(x)$ and write
$$g'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{f(x+2h)-f(x+h)}{h}-\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+2h)-2f(x+h)+f(x)}{h^2}$$
Therefore:
$$f''(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+2h)-2f(x+h)+f(x)}{h^2}$$

To get the same form as you have, you have to substitute $x \to x-h$, then you have:
$$f''(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2}$$

Comment: This is incorrect. You need nested limits, and then things are far from clear.